# How to add custom checkout pane to drupal-commerce in drupal 8

Tags: 8, commerce

I installed drupal-commerce on drupal 8, straightforward and easy using composer.
Now I need to collect some extra information from customer at checkout, and I understood, I need to install a custom checkout pane.

Unfortunately there is no module for that, so I guess, I have to write a custom module. I know how to generate it with drupal-console, but than I'm lost...

It should be possible to copy some of the code from commerce checkout module, but I have no idea where to start. Can someone help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an excerpt from our step-by-step guide "Creating a custom checkout pane for Drupal Commerce in Drupal 8". The rest can be found here: https://ws.agency/blog/creating-custom-checkout-pane-drupal-commerce-drupal-8

"In this article, I'll show how you can create a custom checkout pane for Drupal Commerce in Drupal 8. For this purpose, we'll create a checkout pane with a configuration form and the ability for users to add coupons to their order.

Checkout pane needs to be created with the correct annotation and in the correct namespace. We'll create *CommerceCoupons* class in *module_name/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane* directory with annotation like in code below.

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides the coupons pane. 
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "coupons",
 *   label = @Translation("Redeem Coupon"),
 *   default_step = "order_information",
 * )
 */
class CommerceCoupons extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition,     CheckoutFlowInterface $checkout_flow, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $checkout_flow, $entity_type_manager);
}
```

This means that our custom checkout pane will have an id *'coupons'* and will be labelled as *Redeem Coupon* and will be set on order information step by default.

First, we'll create the settings (configuration) form for our pane. For this purpose, we'll have settings if we, for example, want to set up that user has the ability to redeem only one coupon on order. For this, we'll have to implement four functions.

First, we'll setup our default configuration.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function defaultConfiguration() {
  return [
      'single_coupon' => FALSE,
    ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
}
```

Then we'll implement summary for our configuration form.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildConfigurationSummary() {
  $summary = !empty($this->configuration['single_coupon']) ? $this->t('Single Coupon Usage on Order: Yes') : $this->t('Single Coupon Usage on  Order: No');
  return $summary;
}
```

Next, we'll build our configuration form..." [Continue reading...](https://ws.agency/blog/creating-custom-checkout-pane-drupal-commerce-drupal-8)

Comment: This looks like a link only answer ... please include a relevant quote from that link in your answer ...

Comment: Much better, merci for taking my advice! +1 ... Next answer (or question)?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a plugin in your custom module for implementing the custom checkout pane. a plugin similar to BillingInformation.php in 'commerce/modules/checkout/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane'. I hope this gives you a kickstart.